# leaflet- map disappears after adding a featuregroup and shows up back again only when I move the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, data-visualization

For some reason, leaflet map disappears as soon as I add a featuregroup to mymap.
and it only showed up back again only when I'm using the map or zoom the map.

It feels like I put a grey layer on top of the basemap as the argument say

```
mymap.addLayer(defaultFeature)//
```

I tried

```
defaultFeature.addTo(mymap)
```

Neither them didn't work out from the code below.

```
for(let i=0; i<maplength; i++){

    let coord=[mapdata[i].lat,mapdata[i].lon];
    let circles=L.circle(coord,circleStyle)
    circles.options.address=mapdata[i].address

    markerGroup.push(
    circles    
    )
}

console.log(markerGroup);

defaultFeature=L.featureGroup(markerGroup)
defaultFeature.addTo(mymap)
```

The Full code link is below.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/project/editor/ArGPGJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you add the background color to all elements, also to the tiles on the map.

Change your css to:

```
*{
    color:#464646;
    font-family: ff-cocon-pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}


body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#DEE5E3
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much how did you find out that? I havn't thought of fixing CSS!!

Comment: When I was moveing the map, the tiles are showing and then changed to grey. And then I thought with luck that it can be the css ;)